# Google analytics Embeded API - The OAuth client was not found

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am trying to create the an api to visualize the google anayltics data.

When I run this code it comes up with an orange button - but clicking on it produces a "The OAuth client was not found." error?

Using this code as a sample.
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/basic-dashboard/

```
<html>
  <head>

    <script>
    (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
      g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
      js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
      fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
    }(window,document,'script'));
    </script>

    <script>

    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {

      /**
       * Authorize the user immediately if the user has already granted access.
       * If no access has been created, render an authorize button inside the
       * element with the ID "embed-api-auth-container".
       */
      gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        container: 'embed-api-auth-container',
        clientid: 'UA-104xxxx-x'
      });


      /**
       * Create a new ViewSelector instance to be rendered inside of an
       * element with the id "view-selector-container".
       */
      var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
        container: 'view-selector-container'
      });

      // Render the view selector to the page.
      viewSelector.execute();


      /**
       * Create a new DataChart instance with the given query parameters
       * and Google chart options. It will be rendered inside an element
       * with the id "chart-container".
       */
      var dataChart = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        query: {
          metrics: 'ga:sessions',
          dimensions: 'ga:date',
          'start-date': '30daysAgo',
          'end-date': 'yesterday'
        },
        chart: {
          container: 'chart-container',
          type: 'LINE',
          options: {
            width: '100%'
          }
        }
      });


      /**
       * Render the dataChart on the page whenever a new view is selected.
       */
      viewSelector.on('change', function(ids) {
        dataChart.set({query: {ids: ids}}).execute();
      });

    });
    </script>


  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
    <div id="chart-container"></div>
    <div id="view-selector-container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ideally I want to try and pull the data out of the google analytics component and put it into a custom chart tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

clientid: 'UA-104xxxx-x'

Client id is created on [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project?authuser=0) and looks something like this

```
1046123799103-dmog5dt4cu055g7pf08gitv3i0rlni6f.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

A web property id is from the Google Analyitcs website and looks something like this

```
UA-104xxxx-x
```

Anwser: You are sending the wrong thing.  [Create a New Client ID](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started#client-id)

Comment: Where can this be found on the google developer console? I've found an api key - but nothing like this

Comment: Follow the link for instructions in Googles documentation on the Embedded api https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/getting-started#client-id .  You should be creating Oauth2 credentials not public API key credentials.    IF that doesn't help I have a tutorial on creating Oauth2 credentials as well http://www.daimto.com/google-developer-console-oauth2/

Comment: Cheers man. I found it. Ok I am going to try and make this more sophisticated - is there a direct api data to chart method here.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by Direct API.  However the embedded API uses the core reporting API. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/

Comment: I mean something you call direct - it then spews out raw json, for you to metabolise easily with third party charts. Ideally something without orange button etc..